# Slide toggle for multiple ID

Tags: jquery

I wanted to slide down(or up) all of the #bu2 ids whenever the user clicked #bu id. However, When i clicked #bu, only "First" is showing up. The code:

```
$("#bu2").slideToggle("slow");

<li class="sliding-element" id="bu">clickMe</li>
                <li class="sliding-element" id="bu2" style="display:none;">First</li> 
                <li class="sliding-element" id="bu2" style="display:none;">Second</li> 
                <li class="sliding-element" id="bu2" style="display:none;">Third</li>
```

I recognized that I needed a loop for that. Then, I have tried 
$next("#bu2").slideToggle("slow");
but it did not solve it. How can i make it slide up or down by using ids, without including "sliding-element" class in the process and declaring "Second" and "Third" as different ids?
Thanks

Comment: First "IDs are unique"! Trying to grab multiple equal IDs will always return the first one only.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not have multiple elements with same ids.

Try this:

```
$(".bu2").slideToggle("slow");

<li class="sliding-element" id="bu">clickMe</li>
<li class="sliding-element bu2" style="display:none;">First</li> 
<li class="sliding-element bu2" style="display:none;">Second</li> 
<li class="sliding-element bu2" style="display:none;">Third</li>
```

OR if you want to slide all 'li' elements in one ul, this:

```
$("ul#foo li").slideToggle("slow");        

<ul id="foo">
  <li>First</li>
  <li>Second</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use classes for non-unique things. Also `<li>`s can only and MUST be inside go in `<ul>`s

```
$("#bu").click(function(){
    $('.bu2').slideToggle("slow");
})

<ul class="sliding-element" id="bu">clickMe
    <li class="sliding-element bu2" style="display:none;">First</li> 
    <li class="sliding-element bu2" style="display:none;">Second</li> 
    <li class="sliding-element bu2" style="display:none;">Third</li>
</ul>
```